# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, finding $\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove that:

$\dfrac{\sin(x)^2\log(x^2)}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$

I have got to the following:

$\left| \dfrac{\sin(x)^2\log(x^2)}{x} - 0 \right| = \dfrac{|\sin(x)^2||2\log(x)|}{|x|} \leq \dfrac{|x|^2|2\log(x)|}{|x|}=|x||2\log(x)| $

I don't know how to proceed from here, or if this is the right/best way to start. I hope someone can tell me what im missing.

Comment: Can you use $\frac{\log n}{n^\varepsilon}\to 0$, when $n\to \infty$, for any $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: I have to find an expression for $\delta$

Comment: It's possible if you can use limit suggested.

Comment: You have reduced the expression correctly, but you will need to use a fact like @zkutch says or an equivalent statement like $ n^m e^{-n} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for any fixed $m$, or the like. If you let $x = e^{-y}$, you can convert the limit into something of that form.

Comment: Okay, so setting $x=e^{-y}$ i get $|e^{-y}| |-y|$ and this approches $0$ as $y \to \infty$. And $y \to \infty$ is equivalent to $x \to 0$. Is my understanding of your approach correct?

Comment: Your approach is fine. Since $x\to 0^+$ we can assume $0<x<1$ and then $|\log x|=-\log x=\log (1/x)=2\log(1/\sqrt{x})$. Now use the fundamental inequality $\log t\leq t-1<t$ with $t=1/\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily, changing $x$ by $\lfloor x\rfloor$, reduce the asked (write, if not) case to a fraction
$\frac{\log _{2}n}{n}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let me show some technique for its estimation.

Let's firstly start with $\frac{n}{b^n}$, where $b>1$, and show, that for any $\forall \varepsilon>0$ we can find such $N$, that for any $n>N$ holds $\frac{n}{b^n}<\varepsilon$ (de facto this is limit definition). This easily comes from inequality
$$\frac{n}{b^n} = \frac{n}{(1+b-1)^n}=\frac{n}{1+n(b-1)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}(b-1)^2+\cdots + b^n}<\frac{n}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}(b-1)^2}=\\=\frac{2}{(b-1)^2(n+1)}<\varepsilon$$
Solving extreme right inequality we obtain $n>\frac{2}{(b-1)^2\varepsilon}-1$, so for $N=\left\lfloor \frac{2}{(b-1)^2\varepsilon}-1\right\rfloor +1$ we get desired sentence.

Come back to logarithm. Using what has just been proven and taking $\varepsilon =1$ we can get such  $N$, that for any $n>N$ holds $\frac{1}{b^n}<\frac{n}{b^n}<1$. Let's consider any $\forall \varepsilon_1>0$. We can consider $b=2^{\varepsilon_1}$ and have $\dfrac{1}{2^{n\varepsilon_1}}<\dfrac{n}{2^{n\varepsilon_1}}<1$. It is same with $1<n<2^{n\varepsilon_1}$. Taking logarithm from all sides, gives $0<\log_2 n< n\varepsilon_1$ or
$$0<\frac{\log_2 n}{n}<\varepsilon_1\quad(1)$$
for all $n>N$.

Obtained can be extended to an any $0<\alpha<1$ by following

$\dfrac{\log _{2}n}{n^{\alpha}} = \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \cdot \dfrac{\log _{2}n^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}} \leqslant \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \cdot \dfrac{\log _{2}(\lfloor n^{\alpha} \rfloor + 1)}{\lfloor n^{\alpha} \rfloor} = \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \cdot \dfrac{\log _{2}\lfloor n^{\alpha} \rfloor }{\lfloor n^{\alpha} \rfloor} + \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \cdot \dfrac{\log _{2}(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor n^{\alpha} \rfloor})}{\lfloor n^{\alpha} \rfloor}$
First summand is subsequense of $(1)$ and second can be estimated by constant multiply on $\frac{1}{\lfloor n^{\alpha} \rfloor}$. This can be taken as exact basis for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^{\alpha}\log x =0$.